# image_lib in CodeIgniter not working... code just stops... no error, nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation, gd2

For the life of me, I can't figure out why image_lib (the image manipulation library) in CodeIgniter isn't working.  I have it working perfectly fine on my local machine, so I know the code is right. But when I upload to a production server, trying to create a thumbnail from an image just stops the code dead in its tracks.

The kicker is that image_lib isn't spitting back an error message... the page just *stops* at that point... Here's my code snippet

```
$config = array(
    'source_image' => '/data/servers/misc/www_thesite_com/files/originals/thepicture.jpg',
    'new_image' => '/data/servers/misc/www_thesite_com/files/thumbs',
    'maintain_ratio' => true,
    'create_thumb' => true,
    'width' => 150,
    'height' => 100
);
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$ThumbnailName = 'thepicture_thumb.jpg';
```

I've tried checking using the following code too:

```
if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
     echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

But, nothing happens.  Everything just *stops* at $this->image_lib->resize(); without throwing any error whatsoever.

One other note...  GD2 is successfully installed.  I'm able to perform other standard image manipulation without a hitch when not using CodeIgniter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a login to your server? Maybe you can SSH in and view the server error logs?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I fixed this using

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

just after

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

It seems that giving the configuration when you load the library isn't enough and you need to initialize

Answer (score 2):

If no code executes after your function call, I'd expect the problem to be server related.  This is also true if the local version worked and the production version breaks.

Perhaps your server memory limit is being reached or your picture folder doesn't have write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the requirement to include the subsequent call to

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

This is probably due to autoloading the image_lib library.